# Upload images to folder in OneDrive with OneDrive iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, onedrive

I am trying to integrate OneDrive in my app using the OneDrive iOS SDK. I managed to do most of the things I wanted but I can't seem to figure it out on how to upload an image in a folder(item) on OneDrive. Upload seems to work only if there was an existing image, the one image that I try to upload replacing it.

Here is the code that I am using to do so:

```
func uploadDataInFolder(folderToUploadInId: String, data: NSData) {
    let uploadRequest =     authenticatedOdClient?.drive().items(folderToUploadInId).contentRequest()

    uploadRequest?.uploadFromData(data, completion: {
        (item, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            print("uploadSuccesfull in folder \(item.id)")
        } else {
            print(error)
            print("upload unsuccesfull")
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request as you've constructed it is attempting to modify the binary contents of the folder itself (which doesn't make sense). Try:

`items(folderToUploadInId).itemByPath("image.jpg").contentRequest()`